# How do I declare an array at the beginning of a function, and initialize it later using a defined constant?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to declare an array of chars at the beginning of a function and initialize it later on, using defined constants, for example:

```
#define REV_1    {'A','B','C','D'}
#define REV_2    {'E','F','G','H'}
#define REV_3    {'I','J','K','L'}
void myfunction()
{
    char Rev1[4];
    char Rev2[4];
    char Rev3[4];

    [...a bunch of code here...]

    Rev1 = REV_1;
    Rev2 = REV_2;
    Rev3 = REV_3;
}
```

but I am getting a compiler error telling me

```
Error: #29: expected an expression
Error: #137: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

I have gotten the code to work by doing the following, but ideally I would like to wait until later to initialize the arrays.

```
#define REV_1    {'A','B','C','D'}
#define REV_2    {'E','F','G','H'}
#define REV_3    {'I','J','K','L'}
void myfunction()
{
    char Rev1[] = REV_1;
    char Rev2[] = REV_2;
    char Rev3[] = REV_3;
}
```

What I would really like to do is create a 2D array that stores all 3 of the char arrays, for example:

```
#define REV_1    {'A','B','C','D'}
#define REV_2    {'E','F','G','H'}
#define REV_3    {'I','J','K','L'}
void myfunction()
{
    char Revisions[3][4];

    [...a bunch of code here...]

    Revisions[0] = REV_1;
    Revisions[1] = REV_2;
    Revisions[2] = REV_3;
}
```

Could anybody explain to me the correct way of declaring an array and initializing it later using a defined constant? Or better yet explain how I would go about doing this using a 2D array? I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question, I was unable to find an answer to this question using search.

Comment: Is there a particular reason *why* you don't want to initialize the arrays immediately?

Comment: Basically, because the rest of the variables used in the function are declared at the top and initialized when they are needed, and there is a chance that the code I am adding will not be executed in every scenario so my thought is that it is better for me to initialize them if/when needed.

Comment: All local variables will have random data up to the initialisation, this isn't not usually advisable. @user3380880

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following syntax is valid only when the matrix/vector is initialised.

```
#define REV_1    {'A','B','C','D'}
#define REV_2    {'E','F','G','H'}
#define REV_3    {'I','J','K','L'}
void myfunction()
{
    char Revisions[3][4]= {REV_1, REV_2, REV3};
}
```

When assigning values to an array (assignment and initialisation are different things), that sintax is not valid and you have to assign value by value (for/while loop) or copying blocks (using memcpy), in your case, assuming that you want to skip the initialisation, the memcpy is suggested because of the way in which your MACROs are defined.

Note by the way that while global and static variables are initialised to 0 if there is not explicit initialisation, local variables will contain a random value if they aren't initialised, until you will proceed with an assignment, to avoid this it is usually suggested to initialise them to a known value.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
// Globals:
static const char rev1_proto[4] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};

// In the code:
memcpy(Revisions[0], rev1_proto, sizeof(rev1_proto));
```

This gets around the limitation that you can only define an array using that method where it's declared (not later, like you wish). Instead, you keep a prototype in memory that you can copy in when necessary, using the `memcpy()` function.

This method will work fine with the 2D arrays - it has the assumption that you've already allocated memory in `Revisions` for an array of arrays four characters in length.

Keep in mind that if you're going to try and print out one of the entries in the `Revisions` arrays, it will be missing the NULL terminating character so that won't work. If you want that, you'll have to make the arrays one character longer and add in a '\0' character at the end. Only then can you `printf("%s\n", Revisions[0]);`

Comment: The suggestion on the '\0' is probably very valuable looking at the matrix he is defining.... so I am going to upvote :D

Comment: Unfortunately I am required to keep the REV stored as a MACRO, and getting it from the MACRO into a local variable that I can work with was the part that I was having difficulty with. Your explanation of how to use the 2D array was helpful, but I am unable to upvote because I have a horrible reputation.

Comment: If you need to keep it stored as a macro, Fiddling Bits has the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an anonymous array like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define REV_1 ((char[4]){'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'})

int main(void)
{
    char Rev1[4];

    memcpy(Rev1, REV_1, 4);
    printf("%c %c %c %c\n", Rev1[0], Rev1[1], Rev1[2], Rev1[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> A B C D

Comment: And if you wrap the array with a structure, you could use assignment instead of memcpy, which would be type safe.

Comment: Unfortunately arm compiler would not allow me to cast the array as char[4], and because of its use in other places I have to leave it in the format #define REV_1 {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'} 
I realize now that it is probably a good idea for me to just initialize the array right away

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is "a bunch of code here".

What you want, only works in the 2nd way you described, as it's an initialization, not an assignment.

If you want to do it later, use memcpy

```
memcpy(Rev1, "ABCD", 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something what I think would achieve the closest to what you'd like to have. Unfortunately, I am not 100% clear about how it exactly works out, I only know that it... *works out:*

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define REV_1   (char [4]) {'A','B','C','D'}
#define REV_2   (char [4]) {'E','F','G','H'}
#define REV_3   (char [4]) {'I','J','K','L'}

int main( ){

    char( *Revisions[3] )[4] = { 0 };
    Revisions[0] = REV_1;
    Revisions[1] = REV_2;
    Revisions[2] = REV_3;

    // displays the content
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
            printf( "%c", ( *Revisions[i] )[j] );

            // rest is just cosmetic
            if ( j != 3 ) putchar( ' ' );
        }
        if ( i != 2 ) putchar( '\n' );
    }

    getchar( );
    return 0;
}
```

There is a slight drawback about how you refer to the contents, requiring you to use additional `(`, `*` and `)`, one from each, but that's all I can see.